# Nginx rewrite download php file instead of executing

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I am trying to rewrite some links with nginx, but php files are downloaded instead of executing, if I run the php file in browser is working, so no fastcgi problem.

I already checked other simillar questions here but nothing helped me.

My nginx.conf file

```
....
location / {

location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
    deny    all;
    return  404;
}


location /contact {
rewrite ^/contact/?$ /contact.php last;
}
```

I need to rewrite contact.php to /contact but is not working.

I also tried :

```
 location /contact {
rewrite ^/contact?$ /contact.php last;
}

location /contact {
rewrite ^/contact$ /contact.php last;
}

location /contact {
rewrite ^/contact?$ /contact.php break;
}
```

Nothing works. I do not had this problem is the past...

Comment: Here you can find the best solution for you problem. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26668444/4357467)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I just replaced:

```
location /contact {
rewrite ^/contact?$ /contact.php last;
}
```

with

```
rewrite ^/contact? /contact.php last;
```

Comment: Even better is `rewrite ^ /contact.php last;`, since the `location` block already takes care of matching the URI prefix.